# Button incrementing and firing multiple times on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, button, handlebars.js

So I have a web app that I'm working on, and I have a section of the app that has a deploy button, which launches a modal. In the modal, I have two more buttons, one to confirm and one to cancel.

When the modal launches and I click one of the buttons, it fires once. However, my problem is that if I exit out of the modal, reopen it and click a button again, it will trigger the button twice. This continues if I repeat the process, so the next click would trigger three clicks and so on and so forth.

I've tried using `unbind` and `one` to no avail in jQuery and am kind of stumped at this point.

Here is the relevant jQuery for that section. I can also attach the handlebars file I'm using if that would help.

**jQuery:**

```
 //open modal, present OK and Cancel buttons
$(".inventory").on('click', 'button.deploy', function () {
    console.log('DEPLOY')
    var machine = $(this).data("machine");
    var message = "Are you <b>SURE</b> you want to deploy the following machine:\n\n<b>" + $(this).data("machine") + "</b>";
    var newNetwork = $(this).parent().siblings(".select-option").find("option:selected").val();
    var currentDefault = $(this).parent().siblings(".select-option").attr('defaultValue');
    if (currentDefault !== newNetwork) {
        message += "\n\nChanging the network from: \n\n " + currentDefault + " -> <b>" + newNetwork + "</b>\n\n";
    }
    else {
        message += "\n\nRestarting  with the network:\n\n<b>" + currentDefault + "</b>\n\n";
    }
    message += "<i>NOTE: Any other network changes made to other machines will result in possible changes "
    message += "the next time there is a full deploy.</i>"

    $("#reset-message").html(message);
    $(".jquery-modal.blocker.current").show();
    $("div #reset-modal.modal").show();

    $("div #reset-modal").on('click', "#deploy-cancel", function () {
        $(".jquery-modal.blocker.current").hide();
        $("div #reset-modal.modal").hide();
        console.log('CANCEL')
    });

    $("div #reset-modal").on('click', "#deploy-confirm", function () {
        $(".jquery-modal.blocker.current").hide();
        $("div #reset-modal.modal").hide();
        console.log('CONFIRM')
    });
```

Comment: Attach the modal events outside of **$(".inventory").on('click')** or destroy the modal on hide/close and recreate it when needed.  At the moment you seem to be hiding the modal and reusing it, but attaching a new set of click handlers every time you show it.

Comment: So I need the clicking of the `button.deploy` to trigger the presentation of both the `cancel` and `confirm` buttons, as well as opening the modal. How can I do that if those events are not contained within the click event for the deploy button?

Comment: @JonSG You're a lifesaver! Just figured it out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are adding multiple event handlers.

Try this:

```
   $("div #reset-modal").off('click', "#deploy-cancel").on('click', "#deploy-cancel", function ()        {
        $(".jquery-modal.blocker.current").hide();
        $("div #reset-modal.modal").hide();
        console.log('CANCEL')
    });

    $("div #reset-modal").off('click', "#deploy-confirm").on('click', "#deploy-confirm", function () {
        $(".jquery-modal.blocker.current").hide();
        $("div #reset-modal.modal").hide();
        console.log('CONFIRM')
     });
```

Comment: This helped me. I was running into an issue with the on click handler. This gave me the idea of turning off the event and then activating it again. Like how you have written here. `.off()` then `.on()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this it may work

```
$('.inventory').unbind().bind('click','button.deploy',function(){
```

or

use this it should work

```
$(".inventory").on('click', 'button.deploy', function (event) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
```